# How to make class template

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have to make two classes for Student and Faculty for library system. Every part of code is same for both Student and Faculty class so i thought to make template for both classes. But the problem  is during book issuing(Member to take book from library), Student can take 2 books at max while Faculty can 10 . So I'm making comparison with no. of book issue in past. How should  i design my template that during issuing book to  Student object it compares with 2 while with Faculty it make comparison with 10. 
Is this possible with template or i should make separate class for Student and Faculty.

Someone mentioned this code in answer section . As you can see Student and Faculty has same piece of code except that comparison line of 2 and 10 . Isn't this duplicacy . Can we somehow make template to merge both class . So that is make Comparison with 2 for Student while with 10 for other.

```
std::string title_;
std::string description_;
};

class IMember {
public:
virtual void takeBook(Book book) = 0;
};

class Student : public IMember {
public:
virtual void takeBook(Book book) override {
  if (num_books_ >= 2) {
    throw std::out_of_range("Student can take only 2 books at the time !!");
  }

  books[num_books_++] = std::move(book);
}

private:
int num_books_ = 0;
Book books[2];
};

class Faculty : public IMember {
public:
virtual void takeBook(Book book) override {
  if (num_books_ >= 10) {
    throw std::out_of_range("Student can take only 10 books at the time !!");
  }

  books[num_books_++] = std::move(book);
}

private:
int num_books_ = 0;
Book books[10];
};
```

Comment: What do you mean ? Student can publish book or what ? Or take 2 books ?

Comment: @DenisKotov Member wants to take book from library for some days  to read at home.

Comment: This doesn't look like a good application of templates. Perhaps you want to use inheritance here,

Comment: You may want to use inheritance rather than template.  I use templates when code is the same except for the data type (such as a linked list).  When there is common code, I refactor into a parent class and use inheritance or make a free-standing function.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I know that inheritance can be an option but see code is exactly same except the comparison . 1 do with it 2 while other do it with 10 . So i thought should is use template here.

Comment: When the code is the same except for the comparison, pass a function object or a function pointer.  Example:  `std::sort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```cpp
struct Book {
  std::string title_;
  std::string description_;

  bool operator ==(const Book & book) {
    return title_ == book.title_ && description_ == book.description_;
  }
};

template <uint TMaxNumberOfBook>
class Member {
 public:
  void takeBook(Book book) {
    if (num_books_ >= TMaxNumberOfBook) {
      throw std::out_of_range("Member exceeded a number of books taken at the time !!");
    }

    books[num_books_++] = std::move(book);
  }

  void returnBook(Book book) {
    if (num_books_ == 0) {
      throw std::out_of_range("Member does not have book to return at the time !!");
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < TMaxNumberOfBook; ++i) {
      if (books[i] == book) {
        books[i] = {};
        --num_books_;
        return;
      }
    }

    throw std::invalid_argument("Member has not taken book this book !!");
  }

 private:
  int num_books_ = 0;
  Book books[TMaxNumberOfBook];
};

using Student = Member<2>;
using Faculty = Member<10>;
```

Comment: See in your code Student and Faculty have same piece of code expect that if line one contain 2 while other has 10 . Isn't this duplicaty . Can we somehow combine both classes and compare with 2 if it has student object while with 10 if it has Faculty class

Comment: Hey ! Can explain how issue function can issue book to Faculty member as per your code if num>2 it won't  issue boook . What if that member is faculty member . It should be able to issue  book as for faculty limit is 10

Comment: @NikhilSharma Check again, I removed 2 hardcoded value in my code

Answer (score 0):

Remember that template eventually will be translated into two different classes, for Student and for Faculty. In this case, if you know that you'll have only these two classes, for my opinion, you better write specialization for each one of the classes, instead of using template. 
If you do want to use template, then you will be needed to check the type of the instance somewhere.

Maybe you want to consider to change your design. Case where two classes has almost same code indicates that something with the design is wrong. I would create additional class and pass the object of Student of Faculty to it.